# I'm using graph api to get the users of page, do i need app access token or user access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, nodes

Users authenticate with facebook and login to my app,their access tokens are stored in database, I have created a separate endpoint for fetching pages of a user where i read the user access token from database which is stored at the time of login, and i request api with that access token something like this

```
router.post('/getpages', function (req, res) {
var usertoken;

fbuser.find({ 'facebook.email': req.body.email }, function (err, data) 
{
if (err) {
  throw err;
}
else {
  if (data.length != 0) {
    console.log('somedata', data[0].facebook.id);
    usertoken = data[0].facebook.token;

    console.log('usertoken',usertoken);
    fbuserid = data[0].facebook.id;
    if (usertoken != '' || usertoken != null) {
      //fetch pages here.
      request(
        {
          method: 'GET',
          uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/' + fbuserid + '/accounts',
          access_token: usertoken
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
          console.log (response.body);
          if (error) {
            console.log("sending error");
          } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log("response body error");
            console.log(response.body.error);
          }
        }
      )

    }
  }
  else {
    console.log('nouser found', data);
    res.json("user not found redirect to fb auth");
  }
}

 }
 )
 })
```

and it returns error like this 
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"BKifMoK7jyg"}}

however when i request the api with postman using same credentials it returns the list of pages .what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that’s the correct way to specify additional GET parameters when using `request` …?

Comment: I believe yes, I surfed the messenger api the same way i'm doing here .

Comment: No clue what _“I surfed the messenger api”_ is supposed to mean. // Try appending the parameter to the URL directly … if it works then, then your belief was definitively wrong ...

Comment: I love you bro.. all i needed to do was, qs:{access_token:usertoken} and swap the order of parameters. and it worked